# FileNotFoundError at /success/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/users/2019-10-25-200701_g2suiIo.jpg'

Tags: python, django, face-recognition

I am not being able to solve this problem for my Django project. I am making a realtime attendance system using `face_recognition` library.

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import face_recognition
import cv2




def facerec(request):
    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    # loc = "../media/users/"
    # Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.

    images = []
    encodings = []
    names = []

    employees = User.objects.all()

    for e in employees:
        images.append(e.employee.image.url)
        encodings.append(e.username+'_face_encoding')
        names.append("Name: "+e.username)



    for i in range(len(images)):
        images[i] = face_recognition.load_image_file(images[i])
        encodings[i] = face_recognition.face_encodings(images[i])


    # my_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(input_file)
    # my_image_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(my_image)[0]


    # Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
    known_face_encodings = encodings
    known_face_names = names
    # Initialize some variables
    face_locations = []
    face_encodings = []
    face_names = []
    process_this_frame = True

    while True:
        # Grab a single frame of video
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

        # Resize frame of video to 1/4 size for faster face recognition processing
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)

        # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

        # Only process every other frame of video to save time
        if process_this_frame:
            # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

            face_names = []
            for face_encoding in face_encodings:
                # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
                matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                name = "Unknown"

                # # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
                # if True in matches:
                #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
                #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

                # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
                face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
                best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
                if matches[best_match_index]:
                    employee = User.objects.filter(id=best_match_index)
                    name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

                face_names.append(name)

        process_this_frame = not process_this_frame


        # Display the results
        for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
            # Scale back up face locations since the frame we detected in was scaled to 1/4 size
            top *= 4
            right *= 4
            bottom *= 4
            left *= 4

            # Draw a box around the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

            # Draw a label with a name below the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        # Display the resulting image
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

        # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
        if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    # Release handle to the webcam
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return redirect('/success')


def success(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
    context = {
        "user": user
    }
    return render(request, 'faceapp/welcome.html', context)
```

`welcome.html`

```
<div class="main-content-inner">
                <div class="card-area">
                    {% if messages %}
                        <div class="span12">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ message|safe }}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5">
                            <div class="card card-bordered">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{% static  'assets/images/card/uploadimage.jpg' %}" alt="image">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mt-5">
                            <div class="card card-bordered">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="{% static  'assets/images/card/webcam.jpg' %}" alt="image">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="title">Detect Using Webcam.</h5>
                                       <form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                                            {% csrf_token %}
                                            <input type="file" name="image_file" />
                                            <input type="submit"></input>
                                            {{ form }}
                                       </form>
                                    <p class="card-text">Webcam is used to model a CCTV in this case
                                    </p>
                                    <a href="/detectWithWebcam" class="btn btn-primary">Open Webcam</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block js_content %}
    <script src="{% static  'assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to stream the webcam on realtime and as soon as it detects it, my app will redirect to the success page. please help.

Comment: please provide the template code for `welcome.html` as the problem located in the error message itself

Comment: @LinhNguyen I just updated my `welcome.html`. Please have a look at that.

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback of the exception? This would make it easier to pinpoint your issue